# event.keyCode deprecated, using .key returns null

Tags: javascript, html

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`)
    console.log(audio);
})
```

I get a warning that `e.keyCode` is deprecated here, but if I try to use the updated version it always returns null. Here is what I have tried according to MDN:

```
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="e.key"]`) // null
```

```
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.key}"]`) // null
```

The code is meant to return the key event upon pressing it along with the audio file.
Here is the HTML for reference if needed.
https://pastebin.com/YxKL3vYj

Comment: `data-key="e.key"` vs `data-key="${e.keyCode}"` - One is correct when used with template literals. The other is just a string.

Comment: sorry I just updated after proof-reading, what I tried was ```data-key="${e.key}"``` and ```data-key=e.key``` but the problem still persists

Comment: _"You should avoid using this if possible; it's been deprecated for some time. Instead, you should use [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), if it's implemented."_

Comment: ```(`audio[data-key="${e.code}"]`)``` also doesn't help :/

Comment: _".key returns null"_ - No. `.key` won't be `null`. The source of `null` is the selector that doesn't match an element in the DOM, hence `.querySelector()` returns `null`

Comment: using ```keyCode``` works but not ```code```, ```keyCode``` matches the desired DOM element but not the non-deprecated version

Comment: Then you should try to understand the difference between [`.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and [`.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) (a simple `console.log(...)` would also help)